# Writing to non-Domain file share from SSRS 2012?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We're trying to write to a non-domain file share using SSRS 2012 Data-Driven subscriptions. The subscription seems to work if we write to a file share on the same domain as the SSRS instance, but if we try to write to a share that's not on the domain, we get a "The user account or password is not valid." error.

We can't add this user as something to log on locally because it's not on the domain. We are able to use remote access to log in to the other system as this user from the machine. We just don't seem to be able to use it when trying to write the file. Any ideas on what we might try to write the SSRS files over to the non-domain fileshare?